# PGAdmin4 loses connection on delete query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, pgadmin-4

I'm using query tool of PGAdmin 4 to run some sql queries. SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT queries run successfully, but when I try to run this

```
delete from table1 where id = 5039
```

I get the message

```
The application has lost the database connection:
⁃ If the connection was idle it may have been forcibly disconnected.
⁃ The application server or database server may have been restarted.
⁃ The user session may have timed out.
Do you want to continue and establish a new session?
```

And pressing continue shows the same message again. PGAdmin is updated. The version is 11.0. What can be wrong here?

Comment: Check the logfile of the server. What is your exact Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: Connection lost from pgAdmin4 to your DB server, Check pgAdmin4 logs and/or DB side logs.